# How to make several path elements inherit their stroke from one place?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've got about 300 `path` elements in an SVG, all with different outlines. I am trying to work out if there's a way to make them inherit their `stroke` and `stroke-width` properties from one central place, so that I can change that stroke in one place (using JavaScript) and all the paths will automatically inherit the change (without having to iterate over them and change them one-by-one, which might be slow).

I tried doing this:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <path id="base-path" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="2px"></path>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <use xlink:href="#base-path" d="M655.4122777593284,559.3735699875456L654.1949190078633,555.3887773907059L658.1760111410327,552.9949065234823L662.5848239166088,564.7584631711534L654.5239348866377,566.2861923041205L652.878855492766,562.0062446004627L653.569788838192,559.4960802535879Z"/>
    <use xlink:href="#base-path" d="M668.9348303769535,569.1558517040312L664.0653953710934,566.6527113415123L663.3415604377898,569.6439835699075L661.4990715166535,568.1793081850988L663.7034779044416,561.2718180255733L665.5459668255778,563.7190849448948L668.5729129103017,563.229819290997Z"/>
    <!-- etc... -->
  </g>
</svg>
```

I expected all the `use` elements to be rendered like `path` elements, each with their own unique outline (they all have unique `d` attributes), but all with the same `stroke` and `stroke-width` as the `#base-path`.

But this didn't work. The `use` elements don't appear at all. When I inspect them in Chrome dev tools, they seem to be technically 'rendered', but with zero width and height.

Am I misunderstanding how `use` works? Or is it just not possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

`<use>` doesn't have a d attribute, you can't use it as a pseudo path as you are doing. There's some examples of how to use `<use>` [here](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#use)

As you your main problem though, that's exactly what CSS was invented for. Just create the paths normally as `<path>` elements but given them a class attribute and then set the stroke and stroke-width properties appropriately e.g.

```
<path class="whatever" d="M655.4122777593284,559.3735699875456L654.1949190078633,555.3887773907059L658.1760111410327,552.9949065234823L662.5848239166088,564.7584631711534L654.5239348866377,566.2861923041205L652.878855492766,562.0062446004627L653.569788838192,559.4960802535879Z"/>
<path class="whatever" d="M668.9348303769535,569.1558517040312L664.0653953710934,566.6527113415123L663.3415604377898,569.6439835699075L661.4990715166535,568.1793081850988L663.7034779044416,561.2718180255733L665.5459668255778,563.7190849448948L668.5729129103017,563.229819290997Z"/>

<style>
 .whatever {
    stroke: #f00;
    stroke-width: 2px;
 }
</style>
```

of course if every single one of your paths is the same then you don't even need the class attribute, you can just do

```
<style>
 path {
    stroke: #f00;
    stroke-width: 2px;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was using CSS, but my main problem here is with dynamically changing all the paths' stroke-widths in one go, dynamically, using JavaScript. I can of course iterate through all of them and change them one-by-one, but I just wanted to know if there was a proper "SVG way" for elements to inherit some of their properties from some central definition element (as opposed to a static CSS declaration, which can't reasonably be updated by JavaScript). It sounds like `symbol` might be intended for this purpose, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: It's entirely reasonable to update CSS values from Javascript - see http://www.shawnolson.net/a/503/altering_css_class_attributes_with_javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a quick and dirty example in addition to Robert Longsons reply:  Something like this will do the job:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onclick="
    document.getElementById('dynamicStyle')
    .textContent='line{stroke:green;stroke-width:10}'">

  <style type="text/css" id="dynamicStyle">
    line{stroke:black;stroke-width:4}
  </style>

  <line x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>
```

[Try on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srRqS/) (click on SVG to change the CSS).